# MongoDB repository - how to annotate child class which is not document?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-repositories

I have 2 classes :

```
@Document(collection="student")
public class MongoStudent {
    @Id
    private BigInteger id;
    @Field("name")
    private String name;
    @Field("lname")
    private String lname;
    @Field("studium")
    private List<MongoStudium> studium;

 @PersistenceConstructor
    public MongoStudent(BigInteger id,String name,String lname,List<MongoStudium> studium){ 
     this.id = id;
     this.name = name;
     this.lname = lname
     this.studium = studium;

 } 
...etc, getters,setters

public class MongoStudium {

    @Field
    private BigInteger id;
    @Field
    private Date start;
    @Field
    private Date end;
    @Field("course")
    private String course;

@PersistenceConstructor
public MongoStudium(BigInteger id, Date start, Date end, String course) {

    this.id = id;
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    this.course = course;

}

...etc, getters,setters
```

First class is document, second class is not document.  It give me mongodocument like this :

```
{
    "_id": "1006262",
    "name": "Kugujalu",
    "lname": "Najahalovu",
    "studium": [
        {
            "_id": "992",
            "start": {
                "$date": "1998-08-31T22:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "end": {
                "$date": "2003-06-10T22:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "course": "MCH",
        }
    ],
    "_class": "mongodb.MongoStudent"
}
```

I want to have document in this form, because is easy for me write queries for this document. Problem is that mongodb repository is unable read data from that document. And I don't understood why, because with saving data have no problem. It give me error like this :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: No property studium found on entity class mongodb.MongoStudium to bind constructor parameter to!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.java:49)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.extractInvocationArguments(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:248)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:221)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:86)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:273)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:253)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readCollectionOrArray(MappingMongoConverter.java:978)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1386)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1335)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:335)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:297)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:253)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:202)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:86)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ProjectingReadCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:2827)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2446)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2265)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ExecutableFindOperationSupport$ExecutableFindSupport.doFind(ExecutableFindOperationSupport.java:213)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ExecutableFindOperationSupport$ExecutableFindSupport.all(ExecutableFindOperationSupport.java:169)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.lambda$getExecution$1(AbstractMongoQuery.java:113)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.findByLname(Unknown Source)
    at sk.upjs.nosql.mongodb.StudentService.writeNames(StudentService.java:39)
    at sk.upjs.nosql.mongodb.ConnectToDB.main(ConnectToDB.java:37)
```

It look like mongodb repository miss some annotation. But where ? Any help ?

Comment: Can you add the constructors you have in you code? I believe that it could help to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you removed property 'studium' in MongoStudium but property exists in DB. So Spring try to map in into an object which haven't this field.

You have to remove field 'studium' in all records of MongoStudium in db or clear whole collection in db.

Comment: Well probably. It look that it saved data to new document and read data from old document, because when I rename it don't want work at all. I delete all database and create it again and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the field name from

```
private List<MongoStudium> studium;
```

to

```
private List<MongoStudium> mongoStudium;
```

and the constructor to

```
public MongoStudent(BigInteger id,String name,String lname,List<MongoStudium> mongoStudium){
```

Comment: Well that don't solve my problem, but it start write another error and this time I find where is problem. So thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome :D maybe those different names where somewhat hiding the problem. Please, if you have find the solution share it with us.

Comment: well, solution was delete all database and create new one. It is strange but it It look that it saved data to new document and read data from old document. I really don't know why. Maybe because before this I have 2 document database with same names ?

Comment: Mongoception! Oh my God!